# How to send direct message to specific user in ms teams using python?

Tags: python

I want to send Send direct message to specific user in ms teams through python with Odoo?

Answer (score 3):

This is a little more complicated task, but definitely doable. Sending an individual message using python is not as easy as using Webhook to send the message in Teams. You have to go through Authentication, get your token and then send the chat. Here are the steps that I used to get this to work using selenium to get the Authentication and then using requests.post to send individual massage.

By the way if you thought getting authentication with Microsoft is easy you are 100% wrong, here is the link to getting access token from microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

After you register your app with Azure you can use the following cod to get the Authentication token using slenium.

Set up Selenium

```
import gc
gc.disable() # 03/23/2022 added this one to prevent trash collection and avoide crashing the notebooks
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException # to catch WebDriverException after changing the host from postman to local

Options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
ser = Service("/tmp/geckodriver")
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "location for firefix bynary .. /firefox_binary.py"
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=ser)
```

Use the following code to go through Authentication. ( You need some selenium skills to code the manual process), I'll share the starting point as an example and you can code yours as it is different than the links that I am using.

```
import time
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
Options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
ser = Service("/tmp/geckodriver")
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=ser)


tenant_id = 'your tenant id for Microsoft graph'
client_id = "your client id for Microsoft graph"
url = f"http://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=user.read%20chat.read&state=12345"
driver.get(url)
print(driver.current_url)
#open_tab
time.sleep(3)
```

This is the section that you are going to use your selenium skills, I just put the first step that is required by Microsoft, depending on your/your company setup you may need few more steps to sign in.

```
element_id = webdriver.common.by.By.ID
email_locator=(element_id,"i0116")
driver.find_element(*email_locator).send_keys("your email address")
next_button_locator = (element_id,"idSIButton9")
driver.find_element(*next_button_locator).click()
time.sleep(9)
print(driver.current_url)
```

I recommend printing driver.current_url after each steps so you can manually check the link and then code it accordingly.

After you logged in, now you can use the following code to get your Authentication token. I used localhost:5000 as return Url, but you can set up any URL that you want in your App registration page.

This authentication tokens are only valid for one hour, so I used the following while loop to refresh the token every 30 minutes

```
while True:
  try:
    driver.get(url)
  except WebDriverException:
        time.sleep(3)
   
  url_pattern = 'http://localhost:5000/\?code=(?P<code>[^&]*)&state=12345.*'
  re_match = re.match(url_pattern,driver.current_url)
  code = re_match.group('code')
  
  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  body = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
         'code': code,
         'redirect_url':'your redirect url',
         'client_id': 'your client id',
         'client_secret':'your client secret'}
  
  response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/yor tenant id/oauth2/v2.0/token',headers=headers,data = body)

  access_token = json.loads(response.text)['access_token']
 
  pd_response = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(response.text)])
  # I am saving the new token in spark dataframe where I can read it with other code, but you can save it different way
  sf_response = spark.createDataFrame(pd_response)
  sf_response.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('graphTest')
  time.sleep(30*60)
```

Now if you got through all the obstacle that Microsoft throws at you to just authenticate yoursel, you can use the following line to post a message

```
#used this function to get updated token, but you can pass your token anyway that you want.

def getGraphAccessToken():
  """
  Gets access token that is saved in graphTest table
  """
  dataFrame = spark.sql("select * from graphTest")
  return dataFrame.collect()[0]['access_token']
```

And Finally you can use the following codes to send the message to anyone or group of people as long as you have their chat id.

```
def sendIndividualChat(text,chatIdList,contentType="html"):
  """
  sends individual chat through Microsoft Teams.
  Parameters:
  ----------
  text : str, message content
  chatIdList : list, list of chat id(id is in string format) for individual chat messages
  """
 
  headers = {'Content-type':'application/json',
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {getGraphAccessToken()}"
        }

  body = {
       "body": {
         "contentType": contentType,
         "content": text
  }}

  for chatId in chatIdList:
    requests.post(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chatId}/messages",headers=headers,data =json.dumps(body) )
```

If you dont know how to get the chat id for the individuals or group chat there are few ways, you can use Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer or the following code to get list of your most recent chat with their according chat id. Make sure you send the person/group that you want to get the chat id a message, so it shows up on recent chat messages.

```
def getCurrentChats():
  """
  Gets list of current chats for current user.
  Returns: 
  --------
  Pandas DataFrame with information about the current chats
  """
  headers = {'Content-type':'application/json',
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {getGraphAccessToken()}"}
  connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("graph.microsoft.com")
  connection.request("GET","/v1.0/me/chats",headers=headers)
  resp = connection.getresponse()
  text = resp.read()
  return pd.DataFrame(json.loads(text)['value'])

def getCurrentChatMembers(currentChatsDataFrame,idColumn = 'id',debug=False):
  """
  Get dictionary of member emails for each chat id
  Parameters:
  ----------
  currentChatsDataFrame : Pandas DataFrame returned from getCurrentChats()
  idColumn : str, name of column with chat id (default= id)
  Returns:
  --------
  Pandas DataFrame with ['memberName','memberEmail','chatId'] columns
  """         
  memberList = []
  chatIdList = []
  emailList = []
  headers = {'Content-type':'application/json',
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {getGraphAccessToken()}"}
  connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("graph.microsoft.com")
  for chat_id in currentChatsDataFrame[idColumn]:
    connection.request("GET",f"/v1.0/me/chats/{chat_id}/members",headers=headers)
    resp = connection.getresponse()
    text = resp.read()
    #chatIdList.append(chat_id)
    respJson = json.loads(text)['value']
    dprint(respJson,debug=debug)
    if respJson[1]['email'] =='your email address':# This returns the information about other chat member not the current user.
      chatIdList.append(chat_id)
      memberList.append(respJson[0]['displayName'])
      emailList.append(respJson[0]['email'])
    else:
      chatIdList.append(chat_id)
      memberList.append(respJson[1]['displayName'])
      emailList.append(respJson[1]['email'])
    dprint(text,debug=debug)
    dprint('---------------------------')
    #member_list.append(json.loads(text)['value'])
  dprint(f"chatIdList is {chatIdList}",debug=debug)
  dprint(f"memberlist is {memberList}",debug=debug)
  dprint(f"emaillist is {emailList}",debug=debug)
  return pd.DataFrame({'memberName':memberList,'memberEmail':emailList,'chatId': chatIdList})
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly :

Create a new channel in your Team if desired. A new channel will prevent Python generated notices from taking over other conversation channels.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b3K4.png)

Add a new connector on your desired channel.
[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXtcg.png)

Find the Webhook connector and configure.
[img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfvDv.png)

The configuration required is just a name for the webhook and optionally an image.
[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QjMf.png)

[img 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRL1j.png)
Click create and copy the resulting webhook URL.
[img6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tKPY.png)

Add this code your Python project so that it can write a message to Teams.

```
Install pymsteams with pip.

pip install pymsteams
```

Add this code to your Python project to enable writing messages to Teams, substitute the URL for your webhook:

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("INSERT WEBHOOK URL HERE")
Use this code to generate messages:

myTeamsMessage.text("This message was generated from Python!")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpVjJ.png)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for Channel but i want to send individual user to private chat message.

Comment: ok, let me try that.. if you get that then share here..

Comment: There any way to send Dm user to user with python not bot to user